# How to write a Mongoose query for items whose IDs are not in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two models: `Event` and `People`.

```
schemas.event = new mongoose.Schema({
    eventId: Number,
    name: {type: String},
    size: Number,
    location: {type: String},
    date: {type: Date},     
    people: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: models.Person}],
    note: {type: String}
});
```

and `People`

```
schemas.person = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type: String},
    lastname: {type: String},
    age: Number,
    email: {type: String},
    gender: {type: String}
});
```

Given a certain event, I want to do a Query using Mongoose, to find all the people not already registered for this event.

Something like

```
models.Person.find({not in event.people});
```

The tricky thing for me is, that `event.people` is not an array of IDs, but rather it is an array of Objects that look like

```
[
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b5825"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b58a0"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b58c6"
        }
    ],
```

Is there any way to simply make this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create an array of the ObjectId's by using the native JavaScript method **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var arr = event.people.map(function(item){ return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item["$oid"])});
```

You can then query the collection using that as the **[`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** operator expression:

```
models.Person.find({"_id": { "$nin": arr}}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item["$oid"])` seems to be returning a brand new `oid` which is not what I want. I think I will just return `item["$oid"]` ... edit: but it returns `null`....

Comment: What about if you map it directly without casting to `ObjectId` `event.people.map(function(item){ return item["$oid"]});`?

Comment: Yes, it worked now. I made a mistake in that I was `populating` them before... anyway it works now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following operators:

```
$not - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/
$in - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/
$nin - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/
```

Comment: Just as an FYI: your answer is more of a comment than an answer.